# How to list Higher Secondary Certificate education on my LinkedIn profile?

Tags: india, linkedin, education

I am from India, and we have the [10+2 education system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/10%2B2) here. The "+2" part is termed as the [Higher Secondary Certificate(HSC)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher_Secondary_School_Certificate).

I am updating my LinkedIn profile for the first time, and have decided to list all my college education. What is the equivalent degree from the degree options provided on LinkedIn?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Choose the option *Other* and write "Higher Secondary Certificate" in the text box below it.**

[image: Screenshot of "Other" degree option in LinkedIn]

However, I would recommend omitting the degree, and maybe even the school, from your profile, because if you have a Bachelor's – or higher – degree, then the Higher Secondary Certificate (informally also called 10+2) does not add much value to your profile.

The technically correct answer to your question, though, is *High School*, which is roughly the [US equivalent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secondary_education_in_the_United_States#High_school) of the Indian 10+2. LinkedIn, being a US-based site, provides the degree options from a US context.

The term *High School* has a different meaning in India, and it roughly corresponds to "Junior High School" in the US. Your profile will be seen more often by Indians than Americans, at least in the early years of your career. They would be left somewhat bemused by your "High School" degree, which does not help you much.

Comment: That's so convincing.