# Should I add my primary schools, junior school, and secondary school names to Education of my LinkedIn profile?

Tags: linkedin

From class seven to class twelve, I was at the same institution. Should I separate the Secondary School and Higher secondary school from class/grade seven so that I can give the results of board exams?

Comment: Why not - I don't see any harm in that.. As long as you don't include your kindergarten/preschool.. ;)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to list Higher Secondary Certificate education on my LinkedIn profile?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/81050/how-to-list-higher-secondary-certificate-education-on-my-linkedin-profile)

Comment: Which "board exams" do you mean ? Are they for professional levels such as Law School, Medical School, Dental School, etc... ? or are they for entrance exams to college ? - If you apply for a job, then I don't think you need to list your  Secondary School and Higher secondary school on LinkedIn.

Comment: @Job_September_2020 Thanks. By board exams, I mean the exams taken by our Government for grades 5, 8, 10, and 12 students.

Comment: @gnat, no, that does not answer my question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, no, and only include your high school diploma (or GED) if you don't have a college degree.

Answer (score 29):

No. Nobody cares what you did in primary school.

Comment: but that permanent record!

Answer (score 1):

It depends where you are in your career.  In general you only want to list the last education you have.  If you are into your career and went to college, you’d only list that, or only your high school if that’s all you have.

Now, if you aren’t into your professional career yet and are putting together a resume for some kind of school admission, it very much depends on your country and the kind of school you are trying to get into how much of your school history is relevant, but you’d need to ask that (with those details) on Academics.SE or to a school counselor.

Answer (score 1):

I’d say to go back ten years with your employment (and school/university is about the same), getting very terse around the 7 year mark, and things before that only if they are truly outstanding. So if you’re eighteen, it is just borderline. At 25, no.